# Disable generation of implicit type checking code by swig for python-C++ interface

Tags: python, c++, swig

For the following simple function:

```
#include <iostream>
void Echo(int no) {
    std::cout << "no: " << no << std::endl;
}
```

I have the following swig interface file:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

I can generate a wrapper using swig and test it as:

```
from example import Echo
import numpy as np

no = 2
Echo( np.int(no) )      # OK
Echo( np.int32(no) )    # Error
Echo( np.int64(no) )    # Error
```

swig generates type checking wrapper code which results in error in 2nd and 3rd call. This is nice but is there any way to override/disable generation of this type checking code for the type casting which are legally ok?

Comment: You can rename `Echo` to `EchoInternal` using `%rename` and use the `%insert("python")` to add a function `Echo`, which does the conversion to `int` and calls `EchoInternal`. There is no flags to introduce some sort of relaxation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be controlled by passing `castmode` or `nocastmode` option to swig when generating wrappers. The default is `nocastmode`. This does not require to define any `typemaps` and is also independent of python2/python3.

**Example:** To allow the type castings in above example, one can generate the wrapper as:

```
swig -c++ -python -castmode example.i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a typemap that has the semantics you want using SWIG. The reason the default int typemap doesn't work for you is that it explicitly calls `PyLong_Check`, which requires that your input be an int, or a subtype of it. That's not the case for the numpy types, so it gets rejected, however if we skip that check and jump straight to `PyLong_AsLong` then it'll end up implicitly calling the `__int__` method to make the conversion possible.

So changing your SWIG module to be this:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%typemap(in) int %{
  // Skips PyLong_Check and calls PyLong_AsLong, which calls __int__ as needed
  $1 = PyLong_AsLong($input);
  // But be aware of overflow semantics here. And note py3/py2 differences in PyLong/PyInt
  //
%}
%include "example.h"
```

Is sufficient to make your examples pass.

Note that you could also have achieved the same thing in SWIG by using its overload resolution mechanisms.